# Checking a radioButton in RecyclerView makes other random radiobutton checked too

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, radio-button, radio-group

Im new in RecyclerView and when i use a `RadioGroup` with 4 `RadioButton` in `RecyclerView`.Every things works fine, but when i scroll down in RecyclerView a radio button randomly was checked in to another position 
layout row_myList.xml

```
      <RadioGroup>      
        <RadioButton
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_radio_test2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_radio_test3"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_radio_test1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_radio_test4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/radioGp_testi"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            >

        </RadioGroup>
```

my adapter code

```
public class AdapterQuiz extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterQuiz.MyViewHolder> {
private Activity context;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>quizs=new ArrayList<>();
private static HashMap<String,String>hashMap;

public AdapterQuiz(final Activity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>quizs){
    this.context=context;
    this.quizs=quizs;

}
 @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_soalat,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    hashMap=new HashMap<>();
    hashMap=quizs.get(position);

 holder.rgTesti.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

                switch (i){
                    case R.id.btn_radio_test1:
                        //show a toast
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn_radio_test2:
                        //show a toast
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn_radio_test3:
                        //show a toast
                        break;
                    case R.id.btn_radio_test4:
                        //show a toast
                        break;

                }

            }
        });
    }   }
```

Comment: Yeah , have you done any listener like click listener?

Comment: yes i have it .

Comment: Okay Can you please share your RecyclerView Adapter code and also please make all radio button inside RadioGroup too.

Comment: sure . please wait

Answer (score 0):

Your are on the wrong track... wrap all radio buttons inside Radio Group.

Comment: Radio group is useless without having radiobuttons inside in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need define a parameter in Quiz object for holding selected radio button value (Means which one is selected).When user selected a radio button update Quiz objects value rely on selected radio button value and call notifyDataSetChanged().Then on bindViewHolder set radio button value according to this parameter.Here is example how i used it

```
holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) 
      {
          RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(i);
          String txt = rb.getText().toString();
          int value = Integer.parseInt(txt);
          surveyList.get(position).setRating(value);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  });
```